# Скрытие и отображение элемента на jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Нужно чтобы при клике на li появлялся контент, которой спрятан в li. При клике на крестик, чтоб скрывался.

```js
$('ul li').click(function() {
  $("ul li .popup").removeClass("active").eq($(this).index()).addClass("active");
  $("ul li .popup").hide().eq($(this).index()).fadeIn();
 }).eq(0).addClass("active");

 $('ul li .popup .close').click(function() {
  $("ul li .popup").removeClass("active")
 });
```

```css
ul li {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.content {
  background-color: green;
}

.close {
  background-color: red;
}

.popup {
  display: none;
}

.popup.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <span>1</span>
    <div class="popup"><span class="content">Текст</span>
    <span class="close">X</span></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>2</span>
    <div class="popup"><span class="content">Текст2</span>
    <span class="close">X</span></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>3</span>
    <div class="popup"><span class="content">Текст3</span>
    <span class="close">X</span></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>4</span>
    <div class="popup"><span class="content">Текст4</span>
    <span class="close">X</span></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все что смог придумать со свими скудными знаниями JS

```js
var flag = false;
$('ul li').click(function() {
    if (flag) {
        flag = false;
        return;
    }
    $("ul li .popup").removeClass("active").eq($(this).index()).addClass("active");
    $("ul li .popup").hide().eq($(this).index()).fadeIn();
}).eq(0).addClass("active");

$('ul li .popup .close').click(function() {
    $("ul li .popup").hide();
    flag = true;
});
```

```css
ul li {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.content {
  background-color: green;
}

.close {
  background-color: red;
}

.popup {
  display: none;
}

.popup.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <span>1</span>
    <div class="popup"><span class="content">Текст</span>
    <span class="close">X</span></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>2</span>
    <div class="popup"><span class="content">Текст2</span>
    <span class="close">X</span></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>3</span>
    <div class="popup"><span class="content">Текст3</span>
    <span class="close">X</span></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>4</span>
    <div class="popup"><span class="content">Текст4</span>
    <span class="close">X</span></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```